# searching base URL of a given file

Tags: c

Need some help

1. How to get home directory using C program( e.g /home//
2. how to concat home directory with other directory(/Desktop/ and open it
   as I want to merge as 
   /home//Desktop/
   and fopen(/home//Desktop//text.txt,"rw")

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is Linux (or similar).

The path to the home directory can be found in the `HOME` environment variable, which you can obtain with [`getenv(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv).